# How to log TLS handshake details without `-Djavax.net.debug=all,handshake`

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, webclient, spring-webclient

We maintain a Java 17 application using Spring Boot 2.6.8 and `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient` to perform HTTPS requests to multiple endpoints.

To establish HTTPS a mTLS handshake (client- and server certificate verification) is performed.
We, the client, have multiple certificate-chains in the keystore, depending on the truststore of the server, the client implementation picks one or the other.

**How can I log properly specific information during mTLS handshake?** eg.

- Subject DN of provided client certificate
- Information about chosen algorithm
- and more.

I know about the java system property `-Djavax.net.debug=all,handshake`. But I would like to avoid all the unused details and have more control about what and how logs are written.

I am searching for a webclient-filter-like approach.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: -Djava.net.debug=all prints too much, did you try just **-Djava.net.debug=handshake** ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46240319/175554 may help